# Echo value from this array?

Tags: php, arrays

how do I echo the [subject] value from this array?

Having troubles :P

```
IncomingMail Object
(
    [id] => 27
    [date] => 2013-12-06 12:08:29
    [subject] => Re: Final test
    [fromName] => Name
    [fromAddress] => fdgdfg@dfgfdg.me
    [to] => Array
        (
            [fgfdg@dfgfdgdfg.ca] => 
        )

    [toString] => webby@fdgfdgfdg.ca
    [cc] => Array
        (
        )

    [replyTo] => Array
        (
            [dfgfdg@dfgdfg.me] => Name
        )

    [textPlain] => Plain text

    [textHtml] => html

    [attachments:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an array. It's an object. As such you need to use the `->` operator to access the member variable (as they are called):

```
echo $objectname->subject;
```

Answer (score 1):

jetawe, I think you meant (array) $yourObject, not array($yourObject)

echo $objectname->subject; is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourObject = array($yourObject);

$subject = $yourObject['subject'];
```